# How to open port 22 with iptables

Tags: 14.04, networking, ssh, iptables, firewall

I am not able to ssh into an ec2-instance. when I run `nmap -Pn 10.xxx.xxx.xx` I see that instance doesn't have port 22 open

I have a security group added to this instance that has a `ssh` rule added. I am able to SSH into other instances with same security group. It is just this instance that **lost** all the `rules`

When I try to ssh `ssh ubuntu@xx.xxx.xxx.xx`, I get a connection timed out error

So, I logged in to a different instance with the same security group and trying to run this  `sudo iptables -A INPUT -d 10.xxx.xxx.xx -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT` but that didn't open the port 22 on that instance

Output of the above `iptables` commands is **none**

from the instance where I was able to login:

```
sudo iptables -S -t mangle
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
```

Can someone help me with how I can open the ssh port usign iptables

Thanks

Comment: Hello, could you [edit] the question and post the output of `sudo iptables -S` and if it is not empty the output of `sudo iptables -S -t mangle`. Because `-A` will append the rule at the end of the INPUT chain, probably there is another rule (in the INPUT chain or in the PREROUTING chain) that disallow the access to port 22. You can use `-I` to insert the rule at the beginning of a chain or at certain place.

Comment: Curious, can you please confirm whether you have already created a [security group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/get-set-up-for-amazon-ec2.html#create-a-base-security-group) and associated it with your EC2 instance? And does this security group permit SSH/Port 22 connections? If not, try this first.

Comment: @pa4080 I edited the question. using `-i` didn't help either

Comment: @TomBrossman yes, I have a security group added to this instance with SSH rule